# Eliminar linea de imagenes con openCV

Tags: python, imagen, opencv

tengo estas imágenes y quiero eliminarle las líneas que aparecen, de modo que quede la fecha sin ningún otro ruido. como puedo hacerlo en python con openCV?

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

[image: img 3]

Answer (score 2):

Podrías intentar una erosión seguida de una dilatación. 
Visita la página de OpenCV para más detalle.
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

```
img = cv2.imread(file,0)
erosion = cv2.erode(~img, (3,3),iterations=2)
dil = ~cv2.dilate(erosion, (3,3),iterations=2)
```

El problema es que se pierde información.
A continuación, una solución que conserva la imagen original.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = r'date.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(file,0)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(21,3),0)
ret,binary = cv2.threshold(blur,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
(_, contours, _) = cv2.findContours(binary,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if h>10:
        date = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

Primero se aplica un blur en X para juntar los dígitos de la fecha y unir la línea no deseada. Después se encuentran los contornos, pero la función findContours sólo funciona con imágenes binarizadas cuyo fondo sea negro, es por eso se binariza previamente. Después se obtienen los contornos que tengan una altura de más de 10 pixeles.

[image: Imágenes del proceso.]